# customize the folder of a spreadsheet GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a script that let me create a spreadsheet  but i don't know where it will be created , i want to customize  the place where the spreadsheet will be created .

```
var Today_Submit=Utilities.formatDate(Today_selected,"IST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var Yesterday_Submit=Utilities.formatDate(Yesterday_Selected,"IST", "yyyy-MM-dd"); 
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var model = source.getSheetByName("Reports Model");

// Create a new spreadsheet on Drive, named by date
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create(Today_Submit+" MLD_status Main reports");

// Copy and rename the model sheet into new spreadsheet
var newSheet = model.copyTo(destination).setName(Today_Submit);
```

can you help me please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `SpreadsheetApp` class does not have this. You have to use a mix of `Spreadsheet` and `DocsList` to achieve what you want.

```
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create(Today_Submit+" MLD_status Main reports");
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('myFolder');
DocsList.getFileById(destination.getId()).addToFolder(folder);
```

Note that I haven't actually tested this code but used the reference doc. Please feel free to correct syntax and other minor errors if any.